# User Authentication on external machines

Tags: iis, authentication, http-authentication

Our website has been working and still works if we are connected to the LAN but now if someone is elsewhere and tries to connect, they are presented with the screen called "User Authentification" asking for a username and password. What could have changed?

The website is http://pc.bartselectric.com

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have Windows Authentication enabled on the site.

When logged in to the Active Directory network, IE will automatically pass through your Windows credentials to the site.

When off the network, you have to manually enter your network credentials.

Comment: I doesn't take the network credentials.  I have tried several different logins and passwords but to no avail.  I am still trying.

Answer (score 1):

Check the authentication mode in your web config file is Authentication mode=Windows or some thing else

also check : [IIS Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was the firewall that was stopping the traffic from the outside and they needed to have a username and password to get through the firewall and then it works great.  Thank you for the suggestions.